# Persisting loop dataframes for group concat functions in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, group-concat, persist

I'm trying to aggregate a spark dataframe up to a unique ID, selecting the first non-null value from that column for that ID given a sort column. Basically replicating MySQL's group_concat function.

The SO post here [Spark SQL replacement for MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysqls-group-concat-aggregate-function) was very helpful in replicating the group_concat for a single column. I need to do this for a dynamic list of columns.

I would rather not have to copy this code for each column (dozen +, could be dynamic in the future), so am trying to implement in a loop (frowned on in spark I know!) given a list of column names. Loop runs successfully but, the previous iterations don't persist even when the intermediate df is cached/persisted (re: [Cacheing and Loops in (Py)Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236290/cacheing-and-loops-in-pyspark)).

Any help, pointers or a more elegant non-looping solution would be appreciated (not afraid to try a bit of scala if there is a functional programming approach more suitable)!

Given following df:

| unique_id | row_id | first_name | last_name | middle_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000000 | 1000002 | Simmons | Bonnie | Darnell | 88 |
| 1000000 | 1000006 | Dowell | Crawford | Anne | 87 |
| 1000000 | 1000007 | NULL | Eric | Victor | 89 |
| 1000000 | 1000000 | Zachary | Fields | Narik | 86 |
| 1000000 | 1000003 | NULL | NULL | Warren | 92 |
| 1000000 | 1000008 | Paulette | Ronald | Irvin | 85 |

```
group_column = "unique_id"
concat_list = ['first_name','last_name','middle_name']
sort_column = "score"
sort_order = False
df_final=df.select(group_column).distinct()
for i in concat_list:\
  df_helper=df
  df_helper=df_helper.groupBy(group_column)\
  .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct(sort_column,i)),sort_order).alias('collect_list'))\
  .withColumn("sorted_list",col("collect_list."+str(i)))\
  .withColumn("first_item",slice(col("sorted_list"),1,1))\
  .withColumn(i,concat_ws(",",col("first_item")))\
  .drop("collect_list")\
  .drop("sorted_list")\
  .drop("first_item")
  print(i)
  df_final=df_final.join(df_helper,group_column,"inner")
  df_final.cache()
df_final.display() #I'm using databricks
```

My result looks like:

| unique_id | middle_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1000000 | Warren |

My desired result is:

| unique_id | first_name | last_name | middle_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000000 | Simmons | Eric | Warren |

[Second set of tables if they don't pretty print above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX845.png)

Comment: All the tools you need are in the editor toolbar. No HTML line breaks needed, either.

Comment: @Lamanus thanks for the editing help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question: Add a `.collect()` call on my dataframe as I join to it, not a `persist()` or `cache()`; this will produce the expected dataframe.

```
group_column = "unique_id"
enter code hereconcat_list = ['first_name','last_name','middle_name']
sort_column = "score"
sort_order = False
df_final=df.select(group_column).distinct()
for i in concat_list:\
  df_helper=df
  df_helper=df_helper.groupBy(group_column)\
  .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct(sort_column,i)),sort_order).alias('collect_list'))\
  .withColumn("sorted_list",col("collect_list."+str(i)))\
  .withColumn("first_item",slice(col("sorted_list"),1,1))\
  .withColumn(i,concat_ws(",",col("first_item")))\
  .drop("collect_list")\
  .drop("sorted_list")\
  .drop("first_item")
  print(i)
  df_final=df_final.join(df_helper,group_column,"inner")
  df_final.collect()
df_final.display() #I'm using databricks
```